# What does jQuery focus.bind(domObj) do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, focus

So I encountered this code:

```
setTimeout(domObj.focus.bind(domObj), 500);
```

What does that do in plain English?

What does focus.bind do?

And what would passing a domOBj into the `bind()` function accomplish?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`focus.bind(domObj)` just allows you to bind the `domObj` as the `this` in the execution context of the focus event.

This means that the inside the execution of the method `focus`, you can access the `domObj` using the `this` keyword.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for the full explanation of the bind method.

See [this](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) for the focus event in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript bind is used to create a partially applied function.

The bind method returns a new function whose code is same as the function on which bind was called. The only diff is that , the this value of the new function will be set using the first argument passed in.

In your case , likewise, the `focus.bind(domobj)` creates a new function that is same as focus() except that its this is bound to `domobj`. After the timeout, this new function with domobj set will be called.